# How to understand this code snippet about Numpy.array() datatype?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

The following code snippet is from numpy's webpage:

```
>>> x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[('a','<i4'),('b','<i4')])

>>> x['a']
array([1, 3])
```

I have no ideal of why the dtype keyword argument takes the above form and why the array can be indexed like a dict.

Comment: It's giving a different name and type for each column of your array, similarly to a panda dataframe

Comment: read about structured arrays, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no numpy expert, so I might be a bit off here, but here's my understanding.

We define a structured data type with two named fields, `'a'` and `'b'`. Both of these fields contain a little-endian (**<**) integer (**i**) of 32 bits (**4** bytes).

This is the data type associated with the array we're storing. So every element in our custom datatype takes its first field (`'a'`) from the first element in our array (`x[0]`), and the second element (`'b'`) from the second element in our array (`x[1]`).

If we look at all the values of the first field, `x['a']` we get an array - `[1,3]`.

If we look at all the values of the second field, `x['b']` we get another array, that of the values in the second element - `[2,4]`.

We can have our array store 3 elements but would have to maintain the 2-field structure.

```
x = np.array([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)], dtype=[('a','<i4'), ('b','<i4')])

>>> x['a']
array([1, 3, 5], dtype=int32)
```